# How to get nuxt config inside action of Vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

How can I provide api url to a vuex action in the nuxt project? I'm trying to set in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  apiURL: process.env.API_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/v1',
},
```

Then I'm trying to get it from vuex action, but I don't have it. `context` and `this` don't have that and don't have a `$config`. At the vue component I get by `this.$config.apiURL` successfully, but not at vuex action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference it in vuex thanks to `this.app.$config.apiURL`

Answer (score 1):

`nuxt.config.js`

Add the following:

```
      env: {
        API_URL: "https://",
      }
```

Now you can get it from any file with:

`process.env.API_URL`

Comment: Yes, it's getting from environments, but how can I get it from config?

Comment: Are you not able to get it from the context like this: `action({ $config })`

Comment: No. There is not `$config`

Answer (score 1):

In Vuex Action & Component

```
this.$config.apiBaseUrl
```